# Add iAd to Flex App?

Tags: iphone, apache-flex, iad

I'm preparing to use Flex 4.5 to build iPhone App. However, is there any way that I can add iAd function to Flex App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following frameworks are not available to you if you choose to develop using Adobe's Flex

1. iAd
2. Game Center
3. In-App Purchasing

If you really want to use any of these frameworks then I'd suggest building your app natively using Xcode and Objective-C. The learning curve may be a little steep but it's a totally worthwhile exercise if you want to be able to take advantage of the latest frameworks and device features, rather than having to wait on a third-party to implement them for you.